# Is the input file to a MapReduce program mandatory?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a use case where I generate random data using a map reduce program and I do not require any input file in HDFS. If I don't give input path MR program doesn't work. So, currently I have a dummy input file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually MR programs have some sort of data for processing. But, there might be scenarios like Random Generation where is there is no data to be processed. Checkout the [TeraGen](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraGen.java) program for the random number generation which takes number of rows and the output directory as input. Also, I haven't tried the [DataGenerator](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/DataGeneratorHadoop), but it seems interesting.